# C++ to Objective-C , using a const int in a for loop

Tags: c++, objective-c, protocols, constants

In my header file a.h, I have

```
const int a = 4;
```

in my source file a.cpp ( the extension is cpp, but the type is objective c ), i have

```
#import "a.h"

int func(){
    for(int i = 0; i < a -1 ; i++){
    }
}
```

However, on compiling this, I get the error "cannot find protocol declaration for 'a'".

Why is this occurring and how can I fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you paste the code for your header file...

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can, it's proprietary and I don't own the rights to the code :( If there is anything else I can do to help, please let me know ...

Comment: OK then, just the line where you declare the interface...?

Comment: I'm sorry, this might be extreme noobish, but the above is outside any interface. It's just at global scope. Both these files were earlier type 'source.cpp.cpp' in XCode, and I changed them to 'source.cpp.objcpp'. After changing this, this error started occurring. I don't understand why I should have to declare a const int as a protocol...

Answer (score 1):

In itself, your code is correct -- there is no need for a protocol and compiling `a.cpp` defined as a `sourcecode.cpp.objcpp` would choke if you did.

As a side note, you can leave `a.h` defined as a `sourcecode.c.h` even if it contains pure C++ -- it's how the file that `#includes` or `#imports` is categorized that matters.

I've seen some instances where recursive includes/imports can generate spurious errors like this.

Other than that, It's possible that the XCode project has gotten munged -- have you tried setting up a new skeleton project and adding these files to it?